# Why does NVL always evaluate 2nd parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

Does anyone know, why Oracle's `NVL` (and `NVL2`) function always evaluate the second parameter, even if the first parameter is not `NULL`?

Simple test:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nvl_test RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Called');
  RETURN 1;
END nvl_test;
```

`SELECT NVL( 0, nvl_test ) FROM dual`

returns `0`, but also prints `Called`.

`nvl_test` has been called, even though the result is ignored since first parameter is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's always been that way, so Oracle has to keep it that way to remain backwards compatible.

Use `COALESCE` instead to get the short-circuit behaviour.

Comment: Caveat: it doesn't short-circuit in 9i.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a post where Tom Kyte confirms that `decode` and `case` short circuit but not `nvl` but he doesn't give justification or documentation for why.  Just states it to be:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:926029357278#14932880517348

So in your case you should use `decode` or `case` instead of `nvl` if an expensive function will be called in your query.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it would make sense that the second parameter is evaluated before calling the function, because in general that is how functions are called: all arguments to the function are evaluated and the evaluated values are sent to the function.

However, in the case of a very common system function like NVL, I would have thought PL/SQL could optimise, treating the function call as a special case.  But perhaps that is more difficult than it sounds (to me), as I'm sure this optimisation would have occurred to the developers of Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

They are obviously not short-circuiting, but I can't find any references in Oracle documentation.

Check out this discussion: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3478040