# Select one XML Tag - ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

Tags: oracle

how to extract value from xml with duplicate Tag.

In Oracle, I use this like ExtracValue function to get value from xml string.
but always error : ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node

```
Here is function
=====================
NVL(extractValue(decode(TRAN.RESPONSESTR, null, XMLType(TRAN.RESPONSELOB), XMLType(TRAN.RESPONSESTR)),'//Attribute[1][@Kind = "ContractRid"]/tran1:StrVal', 'xmlns="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd" xmlns:tran1="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd"'),     extractValue(decode(TRAN.RESPONSESTR, null, XMLType(TRAN.RESPONSELOB), XMLType(TRAN.RESPONSESTR)),'//Attribute[@Kind = "ContractRid"]/tran1:StrVal', 'xmlns="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd" xmlns:tran1="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd"'))
```

```
<tran:Response xmlns:tran="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd" xmlns:com="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/common-types.xsd" ApprovalCode="500" Result="Approved" Id="9999995543434040"><tran:CustInfo Kind="Contracts">
<Item>
<Attribute Kind="ContractTranConvRate"><NumVal>0.0002412545</NumVal></Attribute>

<Attribute xmlns:tran1="http://schemas.tranzaxis.com/tran-common.xsd" Kind="ContractRid"><tran1:StrVal>66666666</tran1:StrVal></Attribute>
</Item>
<Item><Attribute Kind="ContractRid"><StrVal>88888888</StrVal></Attribute>
<Attribute Kind="ContractPayeeRid"><StrVal>0000111111</StrVal></Attribute>
<Attribute Kind="ContractTranFeeClearAmt"><NumVal>1600.00</NumVal></Attribute></Item>
</tran:CustInfo>
<tran:Auth PinOk="true" CvvOk="true"/>
<tran:UserAttrs><com:ParamValue Rid="CBSNO"><com:Val>09999999999</com:Val></com:ParamValue></tran:UserAttrs>
</tran:Response>
```

Comment: this works with that XML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does NVL always evaluate 2nd parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021140/why-does-nvl-always-evaluate-2nd-parameter)

Comment: Also note that `extractvalue` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/whatsnew.htm#ADXDB5978) for more than 10 years: use [`XMLQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions249.htm#SQLRF06209) instead